# Get list of filenames pip would install from local folder

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I am using pip to install requirements from a local folder containing `.whl` (wheel) files. I.e., using

```
pip install [package] --no-index --find-links /some/local/folder
```

I'm interested to know how I can get the **filenames of the wheels Python WOULD install** without actually installing them, so that I can copy the wheels to create a deployment.

I've seen some work on a pip "dry run" or ["resolve"](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7819) feature but this is still work in progress. Ideally I would also want transitive wheels to be resolved as well, but this is optional (e.g. `pandas` also requires `numpy`).

---

Example input (requirements.txt):

```
aiofiles
pandas
```

Desired output (filenames from `/some/local/folder`):

```
aiofiles-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
pandas-0.23.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the next day and I've managed to find a solution by myself now. The following copies all needed wheels, including transitive dependencies, into the destination you specify:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links /some/local/folder 
    --dest /will/copy/wheels/here
```

[`pip download` reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/)